# Static memory allocation for array of objects in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, c++98

**Note: C++98 is the only standard available**

I'm trying to create an large array to use as a lookup table during runtime, but I know all the table information at compile time. Conceptually I know I can get a lot of run time savings with static allocation but I'm having some trouble with the C++ syntax for this.

Or, simply put, I'm looking the correct way to do a the class version of

```
const int arr[10] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
```

To get as much savings as I can from knowing everything I want to store in the array of objects at compile time.

Here's an example of my class for entries

```
class foo{
  private:
    const int a;
    const char * b;
  public:
    foo(const int a, const char * b);
    int get_a(void) const{
      return this->a;
    }
    const char * get_b(void) const{
      return this->b;
    }
};

foo::foo(
         const int a,
         const char * b
       ) :
          a(a),
          b(b){
}
```

Can run with this main

```
//Is this array statically allocated at compile time or dynamically allocated at run time with the constructors of foo?
foo arr[2]={
  foo(0,"b0"),
  foo(1,"b1")
};

int main(void){
  for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
    std::cout<<arr[i].get_a()<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<arr[i].get_b()<<std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's not dynamically allocated, the storage would be reserved in advance. But it may be dynamically initialized. Either way everything will happen before it's first used. And are you sure you want to go the "private data with public getters" route? Seems to me you can do with a simple aggregate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array `arr` is allocated statically at compile-time but whether it is initialized at compile-time or run-time can differ between compilers. The safe bet is that your compiler initializes the array at run-time but there are compilers that can use compile-time initialization instead of run-time initialization if the constructors are simple enough.

In C++11 and later you can declare the constructor of `foo` as `constexpr` to make the compiler initialize `arr` at compile time.

Comment: About `constexpr`, you just forgot to say that the class itself must meet the criteria for [LiteralType](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/LiteralType)s, and that all expressions used must be constant (e.g. constant arguments to the constructors). I'm also not sure about copy elision in this case, but I suppose the compiler would optimize it away even if he's not in C++17.

Comment: Also declaring `arr` with `constexpr` will make sure the requirement of *constexpr constructor*.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to tell for sure at which time initialization happens. To check it with your compiler you can set a breakpoint in the constructor and run it in release mode.